# "Overfull \hbox" when using tcolorbox with parskip=half KOMA-option

Tags: koma-script, tcolorbox, parskip

When I use the `tcolorbox` package with the KOMA-option `parskip=half`, I get the error `Overfull \hbox` every time I use a `tcolorbox`. This warning appears despite the `fit warning=false` option of the box.

Everything looks fine, so it's not a big issue, but it's really annoying and "real" warnings get lost between these ones in long documents.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    foo
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

(`fit warning=false` is set by default.)

Comment: The easiest remedy is ***not*** using the option. `;-)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`parskip=half` set a non-zero `\parfillskip`. You could use `parskip=half-` instead. Or set `\parfillskip` to 0pt before every tcolorbox:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{before app=\parfillskip0pt}

\begin{tcolorbox}[]
    foo
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```