# Overfull \hbox with parskip option

Tags: koma-script, parskip

I have a following code

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

and it returns Overfull \hbox.  I figured out that `parskip` option is the culprit.  And yes, I know there was a similar question posted, but I do not know how to apply the solution, because my problem is not related to `tcolorbox`:

["Overfull \hbox" when using tcolorbox with parskip=half KOMA-option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187339/overfull-hbox-when-using-tcolorbox-with-parskip-half-koma-option)

Can you help me with this one?

Comment: If you don't like the `\parfillskip` setting of `parskip=half`, try `parskip=half-`. If you want to keep `parskip=half`, `inxbox` has to be changed somehow to work with `\parfillskip` > `0pt plus 1fil` without warning. Maybe patching in a local change of `\parfillskip` would be possible. BTW: Using `wrapfig2` works without overfull \hbox.

Comment: @cabohah I am aware of `half-`, but I do not know how will "There is no spacing requirement at the end of the last line of a paragraph." mess with the style of the remaining text.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`wrapfig2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig2) instead of `insbox`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This also results in

[image: result using wrapfig2]

but without `Overfull \hbox`.

As an alternative you can also try [`wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig):

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

result in:

[image: result using wrapfig]

also without `Overfull \hbox`.

To get the same result as with `wrapfig2` you need the optional narrow lines argument:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[\dimexpr (3cm+.5\baselineskip)/\baselineskip\relax]{r}{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle(3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess there was a reason why I used `insbox`.  With `wrapfig2` I just get zillion errors in my document and it never compiles to the end :(.

Comment: @Pygmalion If you have a problem with `wrapfig2`, ask a corresponding question (with MWE). My example works without error. BTW: Zillion error messages are seldom the result of zillion errors. Even a single issue can result in lots of error messages.

Comment: @Pygmalion As one more alternative, I've also added three examples with `wrapfig` instead of `wrapfig2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard problem with `parskip=half` in KoMa classes: this option adds some natural width to `\parfillskip`.

Solution: don't use `parskip`. But if you *really* want to produce a bad looking document , do

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}
```

Comment: I just tried without `parskip` and the text is horribly crammed.  I am no expert in typography, but it hurts my eyes.  I can't believe this is the right way.  Between `parskip=half` and `parskip=half-` I see no obvious difference.

Comment: @Pygmalion The idea for `half` is to avoid that paragraphs end too near to the right margin. Anyway, take a book off the shelf and look whether it uses spaced paragraphs.

Comment: You are mostly right, most books with exception of some newer engineering books, do not use spaced paragraphs.  I only realised that now, and I have already wrote several books in several languages the "wrong" way.  I cannot understand why no designer from any publisher ever complained...  I am both sad and angry and who knows what else is wrong with the book I am writing right now.  I'd probably fare better if I wrote books in MS Word and then force publishers do all the design, damn it!

Comment: @Pygmalion I don't like spaced paragraphs, as you have probably realized. But it's not the same as stealing sheep. In the 20's of the 20th century this method became very fashionable, but later the great typographer Jan Tschichold retracted his support to the fashion. Spaced paragraphs can have their use, but in books they're just a waste of space. Experiment: there's no “right way”.

Comment: The difference in number of pages is about 5%, so this is not an issue. The issue is that I put extreme effort in writing the contents, takes years of work to finish a single project! And then I find that one pretty obvious and trivial thing seems to be wrong all along. It is for me difficult to tell what is good, I am so used looking into this design for decades I am no longer objective. There is though one thing I objectively don't like about un-spaced paragraphs.  Because of so many equations you get the wrong idea where are the breaks between different thoughts - equation spaces dominate.

Comment: @Pygmalion That’s why I said there’s no “right way”. However, the indentation or lack thereof after a math display will tell the reader whether a new paragraph is starting.

Comment: Could you please advise me where I can find a designer I can really trust who will look at my document and tell me what else is wrong with it. Of course I realise that this will be done for some monetary compensation. I do not feel able to do the design myself - I am completely lost in this area.